# What is the best Chinese spirit?

Tags: word-meaning

We know the word a "spirit" can mean more than two things. One is a liuqor and another is mind or attitude. Therefore, if I ask "What is the best Chinese spirit?", will it cause ambiguity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word [spirit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/spirit) can mean dozens of things, actually probably more.

When the word is used to refer to alcohol, it is usually in the plural. But then you could ask whether

> What are the best Chinese spirits?

can be ambiguous.

Taken as a sentence, on its own, like just about *any* sentence in English, it can have a range of meanings and even be ambiguous. Sentences can be ambiguous when you know how you are using a word (when you know which types of spirits you mean) and you have a well-defined context. That's the way it is with language.

Comment: If usually  plural, do you mean I have to say "Erguotou are the best Chinese spirits."? Erguotou is the name of a liquor.

Answer (score 3):

Out of the blue? Maybe, though I would not think of non-alcoholic spirits as having a race/nationality, though that might be a matter of opinion.

For alcoholic spirits, it would be more natural to say:

> What *are* the best Chinese *spirits*?

See [***spirit***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/spirit):

> 12) ([usually pl.]) strong alcoholic liquor produced by distillation